# Blazor Server / Asp.Net Core: Http Request doesn't pass user identity to MVC Controller when published on IIS

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, blazor, windows-authentication

currently I'm having trouble getting identity information in my MVC controllers. It's no problem when debugging the blazor application locally but when I publish the application on IIS, I only get the identity of the executing service account, for instance "MachineName\ApplicationPoolIdentity" or "MachineName\LocalService" (depending on what was selected as identity in the application pool settings) in my MVC controllers. On the Blazor pages, however, authentication and authorization seems to work fine.

I got "Windows Authentication" enabled and "Anonymous Authentication" disabled in IIS site authentication settings.

I need the users identity for our audit trail implementation, which creates an entry for each crud operation.

In the MVC Controller I tried using "this.User.Identity" or "HttpContext.User.Identity", which is the same object. When debugging locally it shows the corect identity (of myself as caller). When deployed on IIS I get "MachineName\ApplicationPoolIdentity"

the MVC controller looks as such:

```
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    [Authorize]
    public class DatabaseSystemsController : CustomControllerBase
    {
        // GET: api/DatabaseSystems
        [HttpGet("/api/AllDatabaseSystems")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<DatabaseSystem>>> GetAllDatabaseSystems()
        {
            try
            {
                var identity = HttpContext.User.Identity
                ...
                return await _context.DatabaseSystems.ToListAsync();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                ...
            }
        }
    }
```

I hope someone can help.
Thanks in advance

L.

Comment: Could you please share how you get the  identity information in your MVC controllers? By using `User.Identity.Name`? If possible, please post related blazor and MVC controller codes.

Comment: Thanks @BrandoZhang, I updated my post accordingly.

Comment: Have you tried  `User.Identity.Name`?  Besides, please post CustomControllerBase details codes and how you call this web api. I couldn't reproduce this issue on my side.

Comment: @BrandoZhang, yes, `User.Identity.Name` returns "MachineName\ApplicationPoolIdentity" when the application is published on a IIS server. CustomControllerBase for now is not implemented so there's nothing to see.

This is the api call:

`DatabaseSystems = await HttpClientService.CreateClient("clientName").GetFromJsonAsync<IList<DatabaseSystem>>("api/AllDatabaseSystems");`

Have you tried reproducing on an IIS server?

Comment: This is still not working. However, I found out that when debugging the application locally and using the api url of the iis-hosted application, the api controller on the iis hosted application is getting my personal (=correct) account name. Same result when testing the iis-hosted api with postman using ntlm authentication.
It's only when I run the blazor application from the iis page url, that i get the ApplicationPoolIdentity account name.

I don't get it.

Comment: I'm facing the same problem. Is there any fix yet?
The HttpClient doesn't pass the windows authentification credentials. It passes the credentials of the executing user. Locally on my machine this is working fine because the UI is hosted by myself. But when hosted on IIS the user is the apppool.

Comment: unfortunately, no, I have not found a way to fix this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

To get the user to impersonate use the AuthenticationStateProvider and get the user from this and cast to a WindowsIdentity to retrieve the AccessToken.
This works in both a controller and a razor component.
Inject the AuthenticationStateProvider and then in your method use the following code:

```
    var authState = await _authenticationStateProvider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync();
    var user = authState.User;
    var userToImpersonate = (WindowsIdentity)user.Identity;
    
    await WindowsIdentity.RunImpersonatedAsync(userToImpersonate.AccessToken, async () => 
  {
    
      // Your Code in here to call your api
    
  }
```